# Select in Android using JDBC

Tags: android, oracle, select, jdbc

I'm trying to select the values of a table on  an oracle DataBase and setting the result (the `tudo` variable) on a `TextView`, but when I click on the `Button` on the App, it closes and nothing happen.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private String tudo = " ";

private TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

}

public void onClick(View view){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
        insert();
        // textView.setText(select());
    }
    }).start();

}
protected void select(){
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String url = "XXXXXXX";
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "XXXX", "XXXX");

        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        String teste;
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TTESTE");
        while (rset.next())
        {
            teste = (" " + rset.getString("NOME") + rset.getInt("ID"));
            tudo = tudo + teste;
        }
        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
        textView.setText(tudo);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() 
    { 
          // seu codigo aqui
    });
```